# Null. Empty and Filled count in a postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to count how many fields are null, empty and filled in a table.
Where each column would be a field, for example:

```
select COUNT(1),
  case when table.name is null
        then 'Null'
  when table.name = ''
        then 'Empty'
  else 'Filled' end
from table
```

(**this is an exemple**)

```
FIELD   NULL    EMPTY    FILLED
name     0         2       98
age     10        10       80
heigh    0        50       50
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? This table has about 30 columns.

Comment: What's the difference between `null` and "empty" for an integer column?

Comment: The integer column is an exemple, I have more than 30 columns of various types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each row to a JSON value and then group by the keys of those json value (which are the column names):

```
select d.col, 
       count(*) filter (where value is null) as null_count,
       count(*) filter (where value is not null) as not_null_count,
       count(*) filter (where value = '') as empty
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t)) as d(col, value)
group by d.col;
```

Note that this is going to be **much** slower than manually listing every column like you did.

Comment: wow, this is amazing, I'm having trouble even interpreting all of this! It worked perfectly, I put a limit on some columns and it was very fast, thank you!